# Disable Wacom Pen 12.04

Tags: wacom

I am using a HP tc4400 running on Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04. My Wacom tablet is problematic and automatically shifts (and clicks!) to a corner of the screen. This is solved in my Windows OS by disabling the driver in device manager. I was wondering if it was possible in Ubuntu. I have tried xwacom to Disable device but in vain. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
↳ Serial Wacom Tablet stylus                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ Serial Wacom Tablet eraser                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]

#!/bin/bash
xinput –set-prop 12 “Device Enabled” 0
xinput –set-prop 14 “Device Enabled” 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've disabled the device, that will only disable it as far as the pressure and other services.

You need to know what kernel module is being used for the device:

```
lsmod | grep wacom`
```

The result might be `wacom` or it might be a wacom serial module. you can test it by issuing ONE of these commands depending on your above result:

```
sudo rmmod wacom
sudo rmmod wacom_i2c
sudo rmmod wacom_w8001
```

Once the module is removed, you should immediately be free of the issue. If the issue is gone and you want to make this change perminant, you can add the wacom module to this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add `blacklist wacom` or similar on a new line and save.

If the issue does not go away after removing wacom kernel modules, you have a generic mouse or some other module. Report back here if that is the case and good luck!